# Setting ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME as user variables to use ANT

Tags: java, bash, ant

I am trying to set JAVA and ANT user variables to run ant but it doesn't work.

First I added ANT_HOME : C:\Users\qi11091\ant
and JAVA_HOME: C:\Users\qi11091\Java\jdk1.8.0_40 in my system variables.

Then I have added them in my PATH : %ANT_HOME%\bin;JAVA_HOME\bin

but when i run the ant -version or ant command in my bash I get the line:
"the command ant is written either wrong, or could not be found"

I don't know how to resolve the problem because I think that I configured the variables in the right way.

I also set ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME as system variables but I have the same error.

Comment: Did you close and re-open the command prompt after setting the environment variables? The command prompt does not pick up the settings while it is open.

Comment: Yes I have done it, I have did this :

Comment: You say you've added `%ANT_HOME%\bin;JAVA_HOME\bin` to your `PATH`. Note that you forgot the `%...%` around `JAVA_HOME`. Should have been: `%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`. Do not add any spaces before or after this.

Comment: Sorry, I did not had the time to edit my comment, here is what I did on the bash


`C:\>set ANT_HOME=C:\apache-ant-1.8.1`


    `C:\>set JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk1.6.0_24`



    `C:\>set PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`


    `C:\>ant -version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014`


But when I relaunch a bash and enter the ant -version commad I have the "command ant is written either wrong, or could not be found" sentence

Comment: When you set environment variables with `set` they are not saved - they only exist in the current command prompt session. See [How to set the path and environment variables in Windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Comment: Ok so I have added the path variable with the jjava jdk and the ant bins directly in the path.


`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;C:\Users\qi11091\Documents\Logiciels\a
pache-maven-3.3.1\bin`

Here is what i get wen I run the path command ,It shows me that I have set the path correctly to use ant but it still doesn't work

Comment: This is about Ant, not Maven, right? You have `apache-maven-3.1.1` in your `PATH`, not Ant.

Comment: Yes it is about maven and I wanted to put the ant bin in the path but now it both works for maven and ant when I enter mvn -version or ant -version, it is surprising

Comment: I don't know what was the problem but in direclty putting the maven, ant and jdk paths in the PATH instead of using users variables as ANT_HOME or etc it has worked ! Thanks a lot @Jesper for the help !!